# What are the benefits of Tahujat Namaz?

Tags: salat, tahajjud

What a person can be rewarded of tahujat Namaz ?
And i heared that Tahujat namaz can only be prayed if you slept for an hour or two what if i can't sleep during Ramzan then i can pray Tahujat Namaz?
And also please tell me the Fazaail of Tahujat Namaz?
Thanks

Comment: These are two different questions which should be asked separately as at least one has an answer on the site. Please use meaningful and relevant tags!

Comment: For first of ur question I am keen to know it too and for second part it is said that allah descend the lowest sky as say “if there is anyone who is in need”

Comment: @Nofel that part is already covered on the site so you just need to click on the tahajjud tag and read answers!